# Android NDK calling native method with different namespace

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

i'm new from JNI programming
Can i call a native method like from a different JNI namespace definition?

For example:

```
package com.example.hellojni;
public class HelloJni extends Activity
{
  public native int MyMethod();  
  public native int OtherMethod();   // this works have the namespace package=jniexport interface

  static {System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    int b = OtherMethod(); //works
    int a = MyMethod(); //ERROR java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
 }
}

   ================File.c================
    JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_Cardioline_HelloJni_MyMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj) 
  {
return 1;
  }
   JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_OtherMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)
 {
 return 2;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the JNI method name is predetermined by javah.  Try starting here:

http://blog.edwards-research.com/2012/04/tutorial-android-jni/

javah will provide you with the header and you must copy the method declarations into your .c file.

If you have a JNI method in another class that you want to call, call the other class in java.  Basically change this:

```
int a = MyMethod();
```

to this:

```
int a = new CardioLine.HelloJni().MyMethod();
```

Typically, I have a one-to-one mapping of Java files to .c/.cpp files.  That's probably what you want too (for Java classes with native methods).

Answer (score 1):

As @JonnyBoy  explained in his answer, the name of a JNI native function is tightly coupled with the *full* name of the Java class that uses this function as a native method. The full name of `HelloJni` class in `com.example.hellojni` package is com.example.hellojni.HelloJni, thus it looks for native functions which names start with `Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_`.

Luckily, there is no requirement in Android for all your classes to be under the **app package**. For example, your app that is registered as `com.example.hellojni` is free to include and use a package `CardioLine` and class `CardioLine.HelloJni`.

The directory structure for a simple Android project will include a tree like this:

```
src
  com
    example
      hellojni
         HelloJni.java
  CardioLine
     HelloJni.java
```

On the other hand, if you include **[JNI_OnLoad()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNI_OnLoad)** function in your native library, and use **[RegisterNatives()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#registering_native_methods)**, your Java class can have native methods regardless of their exported names.

Comment: Best explanation I found on JNI naming!
Spread the word: You CANNOT call a JNI function from any package you want.