# How to implement 3rdParty library with Different package name

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface

I have a android project and i need use a 3rdParty library *lib3rdPartylib.so* that's written by C, i already put arch lib into **jniLib** .
There is a conflict between my project package name `com.mycompany.myapp` and so library `com.xyycompany.xyzapp` .

So because **JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_xyzcompany_xyzapp_xyzfunc** i get this error `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for..` , now my question is :

is it possible to integrate my package name with 3rdParty library , if yes how ? if not, is there any solution for my problem except rewrite that C module again.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24229916/192373

Comment: _"if not, is there any solution for my problem except rewrite that C module again."_  Yes, using the expected package name instead of your own.

Comment: What Alex & Michael said. But doesn't a 3rd-party JNI library in Android come with corresponding Java classes that you can interface to (instead of directly calling the library)?

Comment: If your 3ʳᵈ library comes with Java classes, you should use them. But if you have no such classes, you can write them yourself, by reverse engineering the names of packages, classes, and methods. There is no easy way to guess the parameters and return values of these native methods.